# Total variation of complex measure is finite

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on a measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$.  Let $|\mu|$ be the total variation of $\mu$, defined by $|\mu|(E) = \sup \left\{ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\mu(E_j)| : \{E_j\}_{j=1}^\infty\text{ is a pairwise disjoint, $\Sigma$-measurable partition of }E \right\}$.

I'm trying to show that $|\mu|(X) < \infty$.  I know this is a very common result in most measure theory texts, but I don't have one on hand that deals with complex measures; and I'm having difficulty coming up with the proof.  If anyone could give me a hint to start with, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Note here I'm taking a complex measure to be a countably additive set map $\mu: \Sigma \to \mathbb{C}$ and hence $|\mu(E)| < \infty$, for every $E \in \Sigma$.

Comment: You must be missing an additional assumption. Why should the variation of a measure be finite? Consider the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: OK, I see the discrepancy. Some people (such as in Folland and other analysis textbooks) take the definition of "complex measure" to be slightly stronger than the definition I am used to.

Comment: I've edited the original question with a clarification on the definition of a complex measure.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: I've had the same brief mental block as you. Do you know any other definition of "complex measure" that generalizes "positive measure", i.e. that allows for subsets of "infinite" (whatever that may mean) measure? It is annoying to see, as you notice, that according to the definition used in the question, the Haar measure of a non-compact group is not a complex measure.

Comment: @AlexM. It's now been quite a long time since I've studied this material but if I recall one can define a measure taking values on an extended complex plane. Basically one needs a way to take limits. It seems clear to me that this definition is far more complicated than immediately assuming complex measures are bounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: first write $\mu$ as $\mu_1+i\mu_2$ with $\mu_1,\mu_2$ real signed measures, and then apply Hahn decomposition theorem to $\mu_1,\mu_2$.

Comment: Alright, got it.  Thank you!