# Total Variation Measure: Definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

The total variation according to Rudin is defined as:
$$|\mu|(E):=\sup_{\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}E_k=E}\sum_k|\mu(E_k)|$$
where the supremum is taken over all countable partitions.

Now I'm reading in my notes the slightly different definition:
$$|\mu|(E):=\sup_{\bigcup_{k=1}^N E_k=E}\sum_k|\mu(E_k)|$$
here instead explicitely only considering finite partitions.

I distrust this definition also since it refers for proofs to Rudin but I'm stuck finding a counterexample giving merely a finitely additive total variation. Is there some example?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation. Wikipedia defines it using finite partitions, but uses Rudin as a source. Folland also uses finite partitions as does another book I have.

Comment: Also, here's another post that's very similar to yours: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265098/total-variation-of-complex-measure-is-finite?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definitions are equivalent. Indeed, take a  countable partition $E=\bigcup E_k$. By unconditional convergence both the series and its absolute converge. Thus for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that:
$$\|\sum_k|\mu(E_k)|-\sum_{k\leq N}|\mu(E_k)|||<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
whereas since the measure is countably additive there is $N'$ such that:
$$\|\mu(\bigcup_{k>N}E_k)\|=\|\mu(\bigcup_k E_k)-\mu(\bigcup_{k\leq N}E_k)\|=\|\sum_k\mu(E_k)-\sum_{k\leq N}\mu(E_k)\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
Taking both together this implies that the finite partition $E_1,\ldots,E_{N_0},\bigcup_{k>N_0}E_k$ with $N_0:=\max\{N,N'\}$ gets arbitrarily close:
$$\|\sum_k|\mu(E_k)|-\sum_{k\leq N}|\mu(E_k)|-|\mu(\bigcup_{k>N}E_k)|\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$
This shows the desired inequality: $$\sup_{\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} E_k=E}\sum_k |\mu(E_k)|\leq\sup_{\bigcup_{k=1}^N E_k=E}\sum_k |\mu(E_k)|$$
The reverse inequality is either vacuous if "countable" includes "finite", or easy since every finite partition can be made countably infinite by letting $E_k=\varnothing$ for all large $k$.

Comment: I'm not sure wether this proof is right theres just to many steps missing. Can u explain it in more detail, please?

Comment: @Freeze_S I claim that two suprema are equal. One of them is for sums over finite partitions, another over countable. So, given any countable partition, I exhibit a finite one for which the sum is not much smaller.

Comment: Yes that is the idea of the proof but still some steps missing... I tried to unveil these and I think I got it now. Do you mind if add these in your proof?

Comment: @Freeze_S No problem, go ahead and add them.