# Complex Measures: Norm

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Given a measure space $\Omega$.

Consider a complex measure:
$$\mu:\Sigma(\Omega)\to\mathbb{C}:\quad\mu\left(\biguplus_kA_k\right)=\sum_k\mu(A_k)$$

Regard the total variation:
$$|\mu|(A):=\sup_{\uplus_kA_K=A}|\mu(A_k)|$$

Then the norm is finite:
$$\|\mu\|:=|\mu|(\Omega)<\infty$$

Is there an elegant proof?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265098/total-variation-of-complex-measure-is-finite

Comment: @Math1000: Yeah but my route goes the other way round: Complex Measure > Total Measure > Variation Measures > Lebesgue Decomposition > Hahn Decomposition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about "elegant", but there's a straightforward just-follow-the-inequalities proof.

First, if all you want is to show that norm is finite, you can assume $\mu$ is actually real valued. Now say the norm is infinite. So you can find disjoint sets $E_n$ with $\sum |\mu(E_n)|$ arbitrarily large. Noting that $|x|=x^+-x^-$ for $x$ real, either you can find disjoint $E_n$ with $\mu(E_n)>0$ and $\sum \mu(E_n)$ arbitrarily large or you can find disjoint $E_n$ with $\mu(E_n)<0$ and $\sum-\mu(E_n)$ arbitrarily large. Assume the first case.

Taking unions of our disjoint sequences, we can find sets $E$ with $\mu(E)>0$ and $\mu(E)$ arbitrarily large.

So we can find sets $E_n$ with $\mu(E_1)>1$ and $$\mu(E_{n+1})>3\mu(E_n).$$

The meaning of the notation "$E_n$" has been changing from line to line. Fix that; from now on the $E_n$ satisfy that last inequality. Disjunctificate the $E_n$: Let $F_1=E_1$ and $$F_{n+1}=E_{n+1}\setminus\bigcup_{j\le n}E_j.$$Now the $F_n$ are disjoint and the previous inequality implies that $\mu(F_n)>0$ and $$\mu(F_n)\to+\infty.$$So if $F=\bigcup F_n$ then $$\mu(F_n)=+\infty.$$In particular, $\mu(F)$ is unreal, contradiction.

Comment: What is the justification to consider the real resp. imaginary part only?

Comment: $|x+iy| <= |x| + |y|$.

Comment: David, I am sorry, really. Will suggest you edits first in future. Sorry for the trouble! :(

Answer (score 1):

For all $C \subset \Omega$ you can define $||\mu(C)|| = \sup_{A\subset C} |\mu(A)|$, and have the immediate inequality $||\mu||(C_1 \sqcup C_2) \le ||\mu||(C_1) + ||\mu||(C_2)$.

Assume that $||\mu||(\Omega) = \infty$. We'll construct inductively a decreasing sequence of subsets from $\Sigma$  $  B_1 \supset\ldots  B_n \supset \ldots$ such that $|\mu(B_{n+1})| \ge |\mu(B_{n}| + 1$ and $||\mu||(B_n) = \infty$ for all $n$  Let's get $B_1$ first. Since $||\mu||(\Omega) = \infty$ there exists $A \subset \Omega$ with $|\mu(A)|\ge 2|\mu(\Omega)| + 1$. Now $\mu(\Omega) = \mu(A) + \mu(\Omega \backslash A)$ so both $|\mu(A)|$, $|\mu(\Omega \backslash A)|$ are $\ge |\mu(\Omega)| + 1$. Moreover, at least one of the $||\mu||(A)$, $||\mu||(\Omega \backslash A)$ is infinity. We choose $B_1$ to be that one. Getting $B_n$ inside $B_{n-1}$ once $B_{n-1}$ is found is the same argument.

Once we have this sequence $B_n$ we consider $A_n \colon= B_n \backslash B_{n+1}$. We have $|\mu(A_n)| \ge 1$ and $A_n$ are disjoint. However, for every countable family of disjoint subsets $(A_n)$ the series $\sum_n \mu(A_n)$ is convergent so $\mu(A_n) \to 0$. We got a contradiction.

Note that we have used very little: $\mu$ is defined on a ring of subset of $\Omega$ with values in an abelian group with an absolute value. Now if $\mu$ takes values in a finite dimensional normed space we can consider the total variation $|||\mu|||(A)$ as
$\sup \sum_n |\mu(A_n)|$ over all countable partitions of A . That turns out to be finite as well, the proof is just a bit more involved, I'll add some detail later.

Comment: Excellent. +1. Two comments: You _may_ want to consider clarifying why $||\mu||(\Omega)<\infty$ implies that $||\mu||<\infty$. Seems fine to me, but showing this is "deeper" than various things some people have insisted _I_ spell out in excruciating detail. Also you may want to scan carefully for typos. At least one A should be $A$. Consider the expression $||\mu(C_1)||+||\mu||(C_2).$ At least one of those is a typo; I see it both ways in enough places I'm not sure which one you meant. (Seems to me $||\mu||(C)$ is what it should be...)

Comment: @David C. Ullrich: Thank you! , corrected . total variation $||| \cdot |||$ vs $||\cdot ||$ is interesting. In the case of a signed real measure $\mu = \mu_{+} - \mu_{-}$, $|| \cdot || = \max ( \mu_{+}, \mu_{-})$ while $|||\cdot|||  =  \mu_{+} +\mu_{-}$. So, $||\cdot || \le ||| \cdot ||| \le 2 ||\cdot ||$. Similar inequalities hold for measure with values in a finite dimensional normed space, will add to the answer a bit later.

Comment: Heh. The phrase "signed real measures" bugs me, because signed measures are not the same as real measures. (A real measure takes real values, a signed measure takes values in $[-\infty,\infty]$.) Yes, the inequality is trivial for real measures. Possibly no more clear for complex measures than for measures with range in a finite dimensional real vector space?
If you add the finite-dimensional thing you should also answer the obvious question about values in an infinite-dimensional vector space. Example I'm sure you woulda thought of in a second: Oops, out of room - continued

Comment: Example worth including with the finite-dimensional thing: Say $e_1,e_2,\dots$ is an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $H$. Define a measure $\mu$ on the positive integers by $\mu(\{n\})=\frac1ne_n$. Then $\mu$ is an  $H$-valued measure with $||\mu||=\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC. Ullrich: A lovely example! Just to note that it's $|||\mu||| $ that is infinite. Now  for a finite dimensional normed space there exists a constant $c$ so that whenever $(v_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of vectors there exists a subfamily with $|| \sum_{i\in J} v_i|| \ge c \sum_{i \in I} ||v_i||$. This $c$ will make $||\mu|| \ge c |||\mu||$. I should add all this to the answer, with your example.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Nice point! So one could extend this to the framework of Banach spaces. Then the finiteness of the total variation seems to be a property of finite dimensional spaces. *(Or at least your proof.)* So for the general context the total variation may fail to be finite. *(The constructions fit into that of Dvoretzky & Rogers.)*